# Navigation View header click listener not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, navigationview

For some reason the header of my Navigation View is not working for me. I have followed the other posts answers but I still have the same problem. This is my code:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);   

    linearLayoutUserProfile = (LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.linearUserProfile);

    linearLayoutUserProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this,"Click header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Intent mIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            //startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
```

Anyone can give me any tips?

**FIND A**
**SOLUTION, READ BELOW**

Comment: can you post code of nav_header_menu

Comment: I'll post it right away

Comment: I'll already post it @DeepanshuGandhi . Can you help me giving me an up arrow to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and searching I figured out that you don't have to add more xml code after your navigation view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_menu_drawer"/>
```

It's best to leave this navigation view tab at the end of your "activity_main.xml" (Or whatever your xml where your Navigation View is) This is my "nav_header_menu.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
          android:id="@+id/linearUserProfile"
          android:background="@drawable/background_wheat"
          android:gravity="bottom"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_no_picture_45dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNombre"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Some name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```